# Jquery image upload same image not uploading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

am trying to upload multiple images using jquery. but same images are not uploading. how to solve this issue please check my fiddle

```
$images = $('.imageOutput')
$(".imageUpload").change(function(event){
  readURL(this);
});
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    $.each(input.files, function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {           
        $images.append('<img src="'+ e.target.result+'" />')
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this);
    });
  }
}
```

[click here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/q9Lx1Lss/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/q9Lx1Lss/

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Not certain what issue is? `javascript` at jsfiddle appeared to return expected result. No images are uploaded at jsfiddle. Images are read by `FileReader` then appended to `document`.

Comment: use `html` instead of `append`

Answer (score 3):

Just set the value of your file input to `null` once you are done with fetching the URL like below:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Lx1Lss/23/

```
$images = $('.imageOutput')


$(".imageUpload").change(function(event){
    readURL(this);
    this.value = null; //setting the value to null
});



function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        $.each(input.files, function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {           
                $images.append('<img src="'+ e.target.result+'" />')
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this);
        });

    }
}
```

You were getting issue because on second time after selecting the same image, `change` event was not getting fired because of same file selection. Now after adding `this.value = null;` code we are clearing the previous file selection and hence every time `change` event will get executed irrespective of whether you select same file or different one.

Comment: Hmm, I think we have the same issue here. Don't you think that something like `if (input.files && input.files[0]) ) { $('.imageOutput').empty();` is what he needs?

Comment: @Leron - `$('.imageOutput').empty();` and `this.value = null;` is same. Only thing is that; such code needs to be executed after `$.each(input.files` otherwise we will not get the file selected by the user.

Comment: var f = $('.imageOutput').prop("files")[i]['name'];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this);  this is my code , iset reader value empty but not getting output

Comment: @vijayP It's not the same. I don't really understand the real problem of the OP, but using empty after the check has different result than yours this.value = null.

Comment: @kannanD.S - Please have a look at updated fiddle. there I can select same image consecutively N number of time and same gets appended one after other. Please compare your code with http://jsfiddle.net/q9Lx1Lss/23/ code.

Comment: @Leron - If you try the OP's fiddle link then you can't append same image consecutively. By the way you can select same image one after another; but its not getting appended to the DOM. this is what issue faced by OP.

Comment: Just a suggestion: use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using filereader

Comment: @Endless - thanks for suggestion but this code is as per code posted by OP.